# Angular ng-show not working

Tags: angularjs-ng-show

I have a button in a directive that I only want to appear on the last object in the array.  The ng-show evaluates an expression on the controller.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger button-xs tsid-btn-sch-pad
    glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
            type="submit" ng-click=""
            ng-show="{{$index == sc.schedule.length - 1}}"></button>
```

The expression is being correctly evaluated in the browser, but the button is displaying anyway.

[image]

So the difference between the highlighted row and the one above where the delete button is not displaying is that ng-hide was added to the class attribute of the row above and it has not been added to the row that is displaying the delete button incorrectly.  But I don't know why that update isn't taking place since the ng-show expression is being updated.

Comment: First guess is to add parenthesis to your condition, second one to remove the {{}} I don't think they are mandatory within a ng-show

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [$last variable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<button class="btn btn-danger button-xs tsid-btn-sch-pad
    glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
            type="submit" ng-click=""
            ng-show="$last"></button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sf6Xw7YjPlfUuqyHIWng?p=preview

Comment: Nope. Same results.  The problem is not that the expression isn't being evaluated correctly.  It is that the ng-hide class attribute is not getting added to the directive that used to be last.  It must have something to do with the digest loop and the scope. But I don't know what.

Comment: @pthalacker then it should be another problem from your project context, I added a plunker for the proof of concept

Comment: @Flavian Volken Please forgive me, but I don't see how that plnkr relates. It displays the first 9 letters of the alphabet, but I can't see any user interaction with it.

Comment: @pthalacker check again, I saved instead of forking another project by error on plnkr, you were then landing on the wrong version one. I fixed the link.

Comment: @Flavian Volken Your plnkr achieves the same results as I get as far as it goes.  My problem starts when I add a fourth object to the array on the client.  The fourth object gets the last button, but the button does not disappear from the third object.  I could not figure out how to add a fourth object to your plnkr.

Comment: @pthalacker check the plnkr, I added an action on the button which will add an item… no issue here so far

Comment: @Flavian Volken  Okay, that will give me something to work with.  I have changed the design of the UI, so the offending code no longer exists.  I will pull the code out of source control and look again when I get the chance.  I appreciate the your efforts. Thank you.